# How to put page title over featured image in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to put page title over featured image in wordpress?I want the page title and page content over the featured image .
Please suggest.

Comment: Please post your code where you want to change or more details?

Comment: Sorry I don't have one I have just created a  page template and now I want to make the above changes. Please help

Comment: Post that template code.

Comment: Here it is;
`<?php
/*
    Template Name: yourtie
*/
get_header(); ?>
<section id="cir-content-area" role="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">    
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); {?>
        
                    <?php 
                    the_title();
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    the_content();
                 }
                     ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
            
     </div>
 </div>
</section>
<?php
get_footer();
`

Comment: can you show me as an image how would you like to show it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<div>` tag in image and title; Use this code:

```
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: yourtie 
*/
get_header(); 
?> 
<section id="cir-content-area" role="main">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12"> 
       <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');  ?>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background:url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>') no-repeat scroll center center / cover">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content();   ?>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems not working. I actually want to put the page title and content over the feeatured image just like this; https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGSAd.jpg